# Getting other value from list

Tags: c#, .net

I have an existing code base where it is assumed that the list(of string) will have 2 values. Now I have to search this list and get the other value against my search criteria.

```
IList<string> myList = new List<string>
{
    "abc",
    "xyz"
};
```

For example : Here I have search value "abc", but after search I need xyz. How it can be done efficiently?

Comment: you can use myList[currentindex + 1] to get the next value

Comment: If I search "xyz", what should my answer be?

Comment: @Michael: Then it should be "abc"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take the first element in the list after `"abc"` you could use this LINQ solution:

```
IList<string> myList = new List<string>
{
    "efg",
    "abc",
    "xyz",
    "hij"
};

string result = myList.SkipWhile(x => x != "abc")
                      .Skip(1)
                      .Take(1)
                      .FirstOrDefault();
```

**result = "xyz"**